# How to convert Xml to Json format and put into RabbitMQ

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-rabbit

Sending and receiving JSON messages with Spring Boot AMQP and RabbitMQ
How to convert XML to Json format and store into rabbitmq using java
Any one please help me this issue...

Comment: use https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#oxm

Comment: Convert xml to json and store into rabbitmq, Can you help me this @VishwaRatna

Comment: Here is a nice post about converting XML to JSON using Jackson: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-convert-xml-json

Comment: I know xml to json conversion by using jackson but how to put the data in RabbitMQ @Tirlipirli

Comment: I didn't recieve any update for this issue..@Tirlipirli